# I am trying to make a GUI Using HTML, but my CSS code is not loading. I am not sure what the error is

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made two separate files for html and CSS and it didn't worked. Then I added CSS in HTML. After doing that it started displaying the CSS code on Webpage.

```js
/**
 * Load the main menu
 */
assetLoader.finished = function() {
  mainMenu();
}
/**
 * Show the main menu after loading all assets
 */
function mainMenu() {
  $('#main').show();
}
/**
 * Click handlers for the different menu screens
 */
$('.play').click(function() {
  $('#menu').hide();
  startGame();
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu.main {
  background-image:url('board.png’);
}
#main {
  display: none;
  height: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
#main h1 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #AA2666;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  background-color: #FB1886;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FB1886 0%, #B30D5D 100%);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #FB1886 0%, #B30D5D 100%);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #B30D5D;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #B30D5D 0%, #FB1886 100%);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #B30D5D 0%, #FB1886 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-16″>
   <title>Game Engine</title>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="ChessDisp.css" media= “screen”>
  
    
 <script type="text/javascript" src= “game.js”> </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="menu" class="main">
      <div id="main">
        <h1>Game-Engine</h1>

          <h3> Welcome </h3>
          <h2>Select the Game Mode</h2>

        <button type="button" onclick="" >Play</button> <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="" >Pause</button> <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="" >Help</button> <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="" >About Game</button> <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="" >Settings</button> <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="" > License</button>

      </div>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="480">

    </canvas>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js”> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a lot to run but I think there is some issue with the html file.
P.S. I am new to programming, so I am not sure what went wrong. 
I ran it earlier on Pycharm but it was not able to detect link rel command in HTML, the I ran it on notepad and removed link real but it was again not working.

Comment: What does the JavaScript console say? Any errors output? Note that `media= “screen”`, `src= “game.js”` and `src="main.js”` use fancy quotes; replace them with plain old `"`. I also note that `charset="UTF-16″` has another style of quotes as the closing quote.

Comment: First of all make sure you use same quotation marks everywhere, because I can clearly see the difference for example here: `src="main.js”`. After that make sure that your html and css files are in the same folder

Comment: Earlier I used UTF-8 but read somewhere that it was reading chinese characters so I changed into UTF-16. I tried the code in many editors I guess it may be the reason for change of quotes. My all files are in same folder. Javascript console was showing warning, but even though it is not running.

Answer (score 0):

The following css is wrong and will ender all css underneath obsolete:

```
background-image:url('board.png’);
```

It instead should be:

```
background-image:url('board.png');
```

The difference is that after board.png there was a apostrophe instead of a single quotation mark.

---

Edit:
Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fp8t81hv/

I also changed the button class to button element (removed the leading dot) and set the main display to block instead of none so you can see the result. The error of why the css was not working was the apostrophe like I mentioned above. Furthermore you can also see there is an issue with the html as said in the answer of Quentin.

Comment: Nope, that's not the issue I corrected it. I think there is some issue with Link tag, it is not detecting style sheet, is there any alternate to it?

Comment: See my edited answer, I'm sure it will clear things up better now. There is indeed an issue with the link tag. However, since jsfiddle doesn't use that link it still works on jsfiddle. See the answer of Quentin regarding the HTML issue.

Comment: The other issue I am having is that the background image is not showing up. I have saved the image in the same place where all the files are.

Answer (score 0):

You've said `media= “screen”` instead of `media= "screen"`

HTML attribute values cannot be delimited with `U+201C` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) and `U+201D` (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK).

You must use `U+0022` (QUOTATION MARK) or `U+0027` (APOSTROPHE).

Observe the difference:

```css
pre { font-size: 400% }
```

```html
<pre>media= “screen”
media= "screen"</pre>
```

---

Likewise you said `background-image:url('board.png’);` using `U+2019` (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) instead of `U+0027` (APOSTROPHE).

---

You've also used the class selector `.button` but have no elements with `class="button"`. Perhaps you meant the type selector `button`?